# ExtJS Reading JSON

Tags: json, extjs

I am trying to recreate the Editable Big Data Grid from [Sencha's Kitchen Sink](http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/examples/kitchensink/#big-data-grid). I have copied the files exactly (the code is found on the right under the collapsed details window) and the only change I have made is "KitchenSink" becoming the name of my app, "FreshApp". I also copied the BigData.js, Init.js, and Order.js files from the Sencha SDK. My app builds and gives me no errors, but the JSON data does not load, giving me a blank table.

I assume this code (found at /data/BigData.js) is supposed to serve up JSON to `/FreshApp/BigData`:

```
Ext.ux.ajax.SimManager.register({
  '/FreshApp/BigData': {
    type: 'json',
    data: process([{
```

And I would assume this code (found at /app/store/BigData.js) is supposed to retrieve it:

```
proxy: {
  type: 'ajax',
  limitParam: null,
  url: '/FreshApp/BigData',
  reader: {
    type: 'json'
  }
},
```

When I navigate to `http://localhost:1841/FreshApp/BigData`, I get a 404. I have had no problems using XML, but JSON is giving me fits. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It's not a real endpoint, the sim manager hijacks ajax calls and redirects them to the registered urls. They are there for the sake of example. The url should point to either a static json file or a server that will return JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried loading the json directly, without the `SimManager`? Put your json file somewhere on your app folder structure and point the url of the proxy to it as a relative path. Something like this:

```
proxy: {
  type: 'ajax',
  limitParam: null,
  url: '../resources/MyBigData.json',
  reader: {
    type: 'json'
  }
}
```

If this doesn't work either, and your a 100% sure, that the relative path is correct, then you should check if:

1. the MIME-Type for Json is configured in your server
2. you/your server has sufficient rights to access the resource folder/ the file.